# Android: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: android, xml, layout

I would like to implement the color picker library at https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference:

To setup, in a dialog, the xml is added according to the instruction in website, and is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/message_dialog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_round_corners_blue" >

        <net.margaritov.preference.colorpicker.ColorPickerPreference   // error line
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            holo:defaultValue="@color/pumpkin_orange"
            holo:key="color1"
            holo:summary="@string/color1_summary"
            holo:title="@string/color1_title" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Question:

The xml reports error `error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix` at the above error line marked.

What is the problem for the above xml?

Comment: just replace <net.margar.whatever to your package where you add ColorPickerPreference

Answer (score 0):

you have to change this  `<net.margaritov.preference.colorpicker.ColorPickerPreference`  to your package where you add this class like

```
<com.example.yourPackagewhereyouAddThisClass.ColorPickerPreference
```

like

```
net.margaritov.preference.colorpicker
```

change this above to your package Name where you add you ColorPickerPreference Class